# What Should I fix in my C code?

Tags: c

I want to start off by saying that I am not asking for the answer, however I would like some advice on what I should be looking for in the syntax. This is one of my first few C assignments. My code have an output like shown below.

```
How many grade items would you like to enter?   4

Enter the grade for grade item number 1: 67
Enter the grade for grade item number 2: 79.4
Enter the grade for grade item number 3: 90
Enter the grade for grade item number 4: 83.5

Average grade: 79.97%
Letter grade: C
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it replicate for the number inputted however I'm stuck on the below code that I wrote for the first assignment and I understand that loops could have been used to make this a LOT shorter but I have only about a weeks usage experience in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, sum, total = 1200;
   float per;

   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 1: "); // Assignment statements
   scanf("%d", &a1);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 2: ");
   scanf("%d", &a2);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 3: ");
   scanf("%d", &a3);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 4: ");
   scanf("%d", &a4);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 5: ");
   scanf("%d", &a5);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 6: ");
   scanf("%d", &a6);      
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 7: ");
   scanf("%d", &a7);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 8: ");
   scanf("%d", &a8);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 9: ");
   scanf("%d", &a9);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 10: ");
   scanf("%d", &a10);
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 11: ");
   scanf("%d", &a11);   
   printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment 12: ");
   scanf("%d", &a12);       

   sum = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10 + a11 + a12;

   per = (sum * 100) / total;
   printf("\nPercentage : %f", per);

    return (0);
}
```

Any advice would be great(or a link to what I should review?), I get pretty confused after simple print/scan statement.

Comment: There's a lot of things to find on the internet about for loops and arrays in C. You may want to start reading there. "C tutorials" and "C introduction" are also usable search phrases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use a for loop and use an array to store the values. Also don't forget to check the return value of sprintf in case the input cannot be converted to an integer. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d51254d6db5cf117)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` loop to input a number of values:

```
int a, sum = 0;
int n;
printf("\nHow many grade items would you like to enter? ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    printf("\nEnter the score for Assignment %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    sum = sum + a;
}
printf("\nsum: %d", sum);
```

Now when you have the sum you're able to calculate avg. grade and so on.

P.S. Note that questions like "fix my code" are not welcome here. I know that it's not easy to do first steps in learning C. Read some basic tutorials, run example code from them. And try to do your questions more specific.

Comment: Thanks, that does help a lot. Do you have any insight on a good all around resource site for C?

Comment: @Erdowi, I learned C++ in university and Herbert Schildt's book helped me a lot. He has books about C too. Also I used russian online judge system (informatics.mccme.ru) for practice. Look at same sites like Codechef or SPOJ

Comment: @Erdowi, also mark my answer if it solves your problem

Comment: Thank you, I did! I'll be putting up another question soon. I'm stuck on another.

Answer (score 1):

So I am helping you because i somehow know that newbie feeling. First of all the flow of code:

1. Take an integer to get the number of subjects(`n`) and an array(`arr[]`) accordingly.
2. Now start a `for` loop iterating for the total subjects(`0 to n-1`).
3. Now input the values from the user and store them in the array(`arr[i] = marks`) and add the values of the subjects simultaneously in a variable(totalMarks) for total marks`(totalMarks = totalMarks + marks)`.
   OR
4. Directly add the the subjects to a variable(`totalMarks`) if you don't want to print them.
5. Finally Divide the total marks(`totalMarks`) with the total variable as(`n*100`) and multiply it with 100 and store it in per.

   `per = (totalMarks)/(n*100)`

This is the flow of the program.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Arrays are useful but in this case we can do without arrays. We can simple read each value and immediately add it to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

A good measure would be check the data types (int, float etc) of the variables you would be assigning you scanned values to. 
Take a look at "format specifiers".
As for the requirement to show final grade you might want to learn how to use conditional statements.

Seeing that you have relatively low experience i would not suggest more optimizations just yet.

A good resource to get started with C would be [Learning C the Hard Way](https://learncodethehardway.org/c/) which would handle all of your current problems.